# How to determine from which TestCaseSource value is coming from?

Tags: nunit

I am using multiple TestCaseSource attributes. Is it possible to determine which value is coming from which source?

Code example:

```
[TestCaseSource(CountryListA)]
[TestCaseSource(CountryListB)]
public void SomeTest(Country country){
   ...tests on country...
// access the source (either CountryListA or CountryListB)
}
```

There are multiple reasons to access the source, for example I need to check that country is unique in that list, or if something went wrong I want to log for which country in which source the test failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No. NUnit is, in fact, designed to make this impossible. Tests are basically not supposed to know where their arguments came from or who supplied them. This is important in some kinds of advanced test generation scenarios as well as for `[Theory]` tests.

The general approach to this problem is to take steps that ensure your tests are uniquely named. Any duplicates, whether within the same list or between two lists, make it impossible to determine exactly which source is the problem.

The key question is whether the **apparently** duplicate tests are true duplicates. You won't know that unless the Type of each returned argument overrides `ToString()` in a way that allows you to determine the exact case. For example, if `Country` were a class without a `ToString` override, every instance of the test would be named something like `SomeTest(<Country>)`. OTOH, this would not be a problem if `Country` is an `enum` or if its `ToString()` is overridden in a unique way.

In your case, there is a relatively simple way to give your tests a unique **full name** even if the display names are the same.

1. Put all the tests in an abstract base class.
2. Derive two different fixtures from that base.
3. Use `CountryListA` in one of those fixtures and `CountryListB` in the other.

That said, it seems to me that the better approach is to keep the current structure and make the test cases more identifiable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case naming would not help unless I somehow store the source in Country object, so it seems that the best approach is to have one test per test source.